# how much internet traffic is used by an sql query in MySQL & MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, networking

I am having a project where internet trafic is very expensive (metered connections).
Therefore I try to observe how much traffic is beeing used with different methods.

example statement:

```
SELECT Activation from Database.Table
WHERE ObjectID = 2382;
```

```
-------------------------
| Object ID | Activation|  
|-----------|-----------|  
| 2380      | 0         |
| 2381      | 0         |
| 2382      | 1         |
| 2383      | 0         |
| 2384      | 1         |
| 2385      | 0         |  
-------------------------
```

=> returns 1 for example

Is there a method in SQL workbench, to precisely find out, how much traffic was beeing used for this query, or do I have to measure it using Wireshark?

Would http or other protocols use less traffic?

Best regards,

Julian

Comment: Maybe you could also ask this one in dba.stackexchange.com (admin side), since stackoverflow is more oriented to programming questions.